# Mapped networked drives stopped working

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, samba

Just this morning I went to access a network drive that I've used forever and could not connect. I removed the mapping, rebooted several times, followed a few guides on connection configuration, still getting `Network path not found` errors.

I tried connecting via smbclient on a linux host with no issues. I can ping the server, ssh into it, everything. But if I try and map it as a network drive (on this specific laptop), it hangs for a few minutes and then fails.

I can see the host specific log files being created in `/var/log/samba`, but they are empty.

Comment: What happens when you try this on another computer/device?

Comment: Check if the [SMB1 sharing protocol](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/107605-enable-disable-smb1-file-sharing-protocol-windows.html) was disabled in Windows.

Comment: @harrymc I installed SMB1 + enabled, but also forced smbd to protocol v2 or higher.

Comment: @Sickest works just fine. It's crazy.